# Где скачать Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-sdk, intellij-idea

Хотел написать "змейку" для андроида. Не могу найти Android SDK.

Помогите!  IDE - IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отдельно Android SDK можно скачать [здесь](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) (в самом низу страницы).

Однако для написания приложений под Android **лучше** использовать Android Studio (которая, кстати, построена как раз на IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: Оно точно ещё там есть?

Comment: @МишаковМаксим, Да, есть.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE:

Скачать https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools

> If you do not need Android Studio, you can download the basic Android command line tools below. You can use the included sdkmanager to download other SDK packages.

Далее:  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager

Для линукс инструкция: https://guides.codepath.com/android/installing-android-sdk-tools

Comment: Все там на месте, секция "Command line tools only" в конце страницы, под три основные платформы

Comment: Command line tools only и SDK - это раные вещи. Как минимум IDEA не распознает в них SDK

Comment: там есть sdkmanager для того, чтобы скачать компоненты сдк